# how could we get the height of given value in Binary Search Tree(when the given value is String)

Tags: java, data-structures, binary-search-tree

I am trying to implement a Height Method of Binary Search Tree.
But the input parameter has to be only String. I know how to do when input parameter is Node class. But I couldn't figure it out with String type given value.

```
public int height(E e) {

  int  nodeHeight=-1;

  if(root==null)
  {
      return nodeHeight;
  }

  if(e.equals(root.element))
  {
      return nodeHeight+1;
  }

  else 

      return 1+Math.max(height(root.left.element), height(root.right.element));
```

For example. there should has some people's Names that store in a binary tree. When I call height(Jimmy).  the methods should tell me what is the height of Jimmy in this current binary Tree. By the way, the input parameter can only be String.

edit: I try to implement another way to get the height

```
 public int height(E e)
{
    int nodeHeight=-1;
    TreeNode<E> current=root;
    if(root==null)
    {
        return nodeHeight;
    }

    if(current.element==e)
    {
        return nodeHeight+1;
    }

    else if(e.compareTo(current.element)>0)
    {
        current=current.right;
        nodeHeight=height(current.element);

    }

    else if(e.compareTo(current.element)<0)
    {
        current=current.left;
        nodeHeight=height(current.element);
    }

    return nodeHeight;
} // (end height)
```

but the error I am getting is StackOverFlow.

Comment: What exactly is the "height of Jimmy"? The nodes above it in the tree or the height of the subtree below it?

Comment: for example, you add many people's name into a binary tree. then "jimmy" is the given value that you want to find the height of it.  I want to find the height of "jimmy" in this binary search tree

Comment: This does not answer my question. You again just referred to "height" without explaining what it is.

Comment: for example,  the height of root.element("Jane") is 0, the height of root.left.element("jimmy") is 1,  it match the input parameter, so then just return the height=1.

Comment: Ok, so just do a normal search for the node and while doing so, count how many nodes you visit before finding the value.

Comment: I always getting the error of StackOverFlow. seems like the recursive goes too deep.

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming what you want is deepest depth. However, it's hard to tell because your code will only work if the element you are searching for the root element. If it isn't the root element, it will go in an infinite recursion and eventually crash.

Comment: Does it answer the question posted ? If not please do not post as answer.

Comment: I am actually not finding the deepest depth, but the given value's depth, for example, the root element is Jane,   the root.left element is jimmy  the height of given value("Jimmy") 's height is 1. so return height=1;